# Editing multiple objects with simple_form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form

In the Railscast dealing with [Editing Multiple](http://railscasts.com/episodes/165-edit-multiple-revised?view=asciicast]), Ryan shows how to edit multiple objects in batch with `form_tag`.  Is there a good way to do this using simple_form?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The base-case for using form_for or simple_form_for helpers are to hand them an ActiveRecord model...

```
<%= form_for @zebra do |f| %>
```

...which doesn't work in this case because you're not creating a form for one single instance of an ActiveRecord model. In the RailsCast, this is why Ryan uses form_tag.

There isn't a simple_form_tag, but you can hand simple_form a :symbol instead. [Check out this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5181143/simpleform-without-for-non-model-form) to see how some folks approached a similar problem. Know that at that point, you're writing a lot of extra code for simple_form to do what the RailsCast code does instead, and you lose a lot of the built-in niceties of simple_form.

There might be really good reasons why you'd battle with simple_form in this non-ideal scenario. If it were me, I'd start with the RailsCast code, get it working, and worry about niceties second. :)