# Undefined method error when using simple_form (newbie)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form

I've got the following simple_form:

```
= simple_form_for instance do |f|
  = f.input :update_resolution, collection: 1..10
  = f.button :submit
```

It throws the error:

```
undefined method `update_resolution' for #<Instance:0x007f0c07329640>
```

In `instances_controller.rb` I have:

```
  def update_resolution 
    render nothing: true, status: 200, content_type: 'text/html'
  end
```

And I'm not 100% sure what's best to put in `routes.rb`.

**Goal**: I'm trying make an auto-submitting dropdown to allow the user to run update_resolution with certain params.

Questions:

1. Why does it throw this error & how can I fix it?
2. What is the preferred `routes.rb` strategy?

Comment: Can you please show your model code?

Comment: update_resolution is your controller method which you are trying to call in view?

Comment: Inside a form you are trying to call **controller action**,... What the heck! :/

Comment: Your `f` is a model object, and you can call the methods which are defined inside the models as instance method on `f`... not the controller actions..

Comment: OP, before you move a single step, please read this - http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html .. You will get the idea.

Comment: from your controller action what you are trying to do?

Comment: maybe you are looking for a model less form. where your form does not perform any action on items on DB. if that is the case then something like this will be the way to go. http://stackoverflow.com/a/5181627/827770

Comment: @ArslanAli I am upset. :/ .. Why not some tutorials people try and then jump into the actual development.. :(

Comment: @ArupRakshit I agree.

Comment: @ArslanAli Thanks Bro! for understanding. I didn't want to be _rude_, I just got shocked.. Myself also still _newbie_ in Rails. It is huge and full loaded with lots of useful features. I am still swimming at the corner of it..

Comment: The problem is, I can't pass any params into the model, hence I moved it into the controller. I also think the controller *is* the right place for this kind of action (it's not a saved attribute, just do something and quit). I'm not sure what to put where, and hence make the form work.

Comment: @cjm2671 You can pass the `params` value to the model method, by calling the methods of model inside the controller and `params` as arguments to those methods..

Comment: OK, I understand, but how do I then call the controller method from the form?

Comment: `form_for` is there to create input fields not anything else more.. I am not sure what you want to do ?

Comment: Well I wanted a form generator rather than having to code html elements myself - that's what I was trying to avoid.

Comment: @cjm2671 do look at the model less simple_form choice I mentioned in my previous comment. I am also posting it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be achieved with a model less simple_form. Look at the following code:

```
<%= simple_form_for :user, url: users_path do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :name, as: :string %>
  ...
<% end %>
```

`url: users_path` can be changed to the action you want it to post to. In your case `update_resolution_instance_path` The action will take the params being passed to it and do whatever it needs to do.

I am using something similar to be able to take data from fields and then send an email to the user entered email address.