# What benefits does simple_form provide when used without a model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form

The answers in [SimpleForm without for (non model form)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5181143/simpleform-without-for-non-model-form) indicate that it's possible to create a form using SimpleForm without a model being used.

However, I don't know whether it makes sense to do so.

What benefits does SimpleForm provide over the forms generated by Rails when you don't have a model object involved?

Comment: I'd say automatic markup?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The benefit that it provides is that you don't have to build any html around your fields, and add classes to them, if you properly configured `simple_form`. Because for example for bootstrap you mostly will have some wrappers around your inputs.

And you also have automatic error messages in your form this way.