# Dynamic fields using Simple Form and AJAX

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, simple-form

I want to generate a selection box that depends on the user input.
I am now thinking of using a partial form to achieve it. However, is it possible to make use of simple_form to generate some dynamic fields while I can skip creating "form tag"?

Comment: If I get it right you want to do something like: 'user types into a text field -> then a selection box will be generated based on what user entered -> then you want this selection_box be generated using simple_form_for?

Comment: If that so, then you were asking how to use simple_form_for  versus form_tag in such a way that simple_form_for expects a resource inputted like <%= simple_form_for @user ... %> compared with <%= form_tag url %> because your form doesn't really have a resource to be passed in  simple_form?

Comment: Exactly, this is what I want to ask.

Comment: This may help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5181143/simpleform-without-for-non-model-form